# Issue when using openfeign client called within an asynchronous method

Tags: java, spring, load-balancing, feign

I encounter this error when calling a service asynchronously using Feign after a migration from Java 8 to Java 17 and to spring 3

```
    {
      "code": "SI-SERVICE-ERROR-000500",
      "message": "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration   class [org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.annotation.LoadBalancerClientConfiguration]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    }
```

My Feign and Main class :

```
@Service
@FeignClient(name = "si-booking-service", path = "/si-booking-service/bookings")
public interface SIBookingServiceClient {...}


@EnableFeignClients
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MainApplication {..}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is an open bug in the spring cloud Feign :
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/475

These are the version numbers of my project dependencies :

```
Spring boot 3.1.0
spring-cloud 2022.0.3
Java 17
```

This workaround works for me (I added this method in my WebclientConfiguration class)  :

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class WebclientConfiguration {
...

 @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  public LoadBalancerClientFactory loadBalancerClientFactory(LoadBalancerClientsProperties properties) {
    return new LoadBalancerClientFactory(properties) {
      @Override public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext createContext(String name) {
        ClassLoader originalClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) super.createContext(name);
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(originalClassLoader);
        return context;
      }
    };
  }
}
```